# Unsuccessful Linq query to retrieve data of composite key table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, ef-code-first

Hi i would like to write a linq query to retrieve all data of a composite table which is generated as a result of many to many relationship.

This is my query in controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var act = (from i in _context.act
                   from j in _context.mvz
                   where i.Id == j.Id
                   select i).ToList();


        var mvz = _context.mvz.ToList();
        var vm = new AAMMViewModel()
        {
            actz = act
            mvz = mvz
        };
        if (vm == null)
        {
            return Content("No items found in database");
        }
        return View(vm);
    }
```

This is view model

```
  public class AAMMViewModel
{
    public List<Actors> actz { get; set; }
    public List<Movies> mvz { get; set; }
    public AAMMViewModel()
    {
        actz = new List<Actors>();
        mvz = new List<Movies>();
    }
}
```

It does not gives the desired result, I know that something is wrong with the logic of my Linq query. 
Please guide me if anyone has expertise in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var act = 
    (from i in _context.act
    where i.Id.SelectMany(id => _context.mvz.Contains(id.Id))
    select i).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you but it is giving an error, not supporting the All(), it says it does not contain a definition for All()

Comment: Does not support that too, in fact after I.Id it opens a list that contains only a few things, like compare to, equals, get hashcode, gettype, gettypecode and tostring.... All() and SelectMany() is not in the list and not supported, are we missing a namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the ids of Actors and Movies are same. If yes, do the join and use the right property name. You are using act in place of actz in your linq

```
public class AAMMViewModel
{
    public List<Actors> actz { get; set; }
    public List<Movies> mvz { get; set; }
    public AAMMViewModel()
    {
        actz = new List<Actors>();
        mvz = new List<Movies>();
    }
}

var act = (from i in _context.actz
                   join j in _context.mvz ON i.Id == j.Id
                   select i).ToList();
```

Comment: Hello, no the ids are not same, its just an example and i am struggling to create the logic itself, I want to retrieve all actor ids that contain movie ids.. in other words whatever exist in the composite key table..